# A numpy/scipy function to calculate the "polynomial coefficient"

Tags: python, math, numpy, polynomials

Is there any python function (perhaps from numpy or scipy) that calculates the coefficient of `x**r` in the expansion of `(1+x+x**2+x**3+...+x**(k-1))**n`, where `k>=1`, `n>=0` and `0<=r<=n(k-1)`?

This is sometimes called **polynomial coefficient (PC)** (see, for example, [here](http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf)).

If not, can you think of an efficient way to calculate it? (I am not interested in the naive/greedy way).

Comment: I think this can be solved in closed form, maybe better suited to math stackexchange.

Comment: Or have a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html

Comment: @Louis - are you sure the link you have provided is relevant?

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the naive/greedy way?

Comment: @larsmans - one naive way would be to loop over all combinations of length `n` from `0,...,k-1`, and count each whose sum is `r`.

Comment: Oh, right, I misread the question. I thought you just wanted to evaluate that formula.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively doing an `n`-fold convolution of [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1].
As such, have you considered using an FFT on a sufficiently zero padded array, raising its elements to the power `n` and using the inverse FFT to recover all of the coefficients of

```
(1+x+x**2+x**3+...+x**(k-1))**n
```

and then just reading off the ones you are interested in?

**UPDATE**:

Since the FFT is cyclic, you'll need an array that is no smaller than the number of terms in

```
(1+x+x**2+x**3+...+x**(k-1))**n
```

or, in other words, `(k-1)*n+1` so that the results don't wrap around at the ends (or at least so when they do they only add zeros to affected elements). Often its length should also be a power of two since this is required by the FFT algorithm (implementations that don't require it to will pad your input with zeros until it does).

In C-like pseudocode:

```
unsigned int m = 1;
while(m<(k-1)*n+1) m *= 2;

complex c[m];
for(unsigned int i=0;i!=k;++i) c[i] = complex(1.0, 0.0);
for(unsigned int i=k;i!=m;++i) c[i] = complex(0.0, 0.0);

c = fft(c);
for(unsigned int i=0;i!=m;++i) c[i] = pow(c[i], double(n));
c = inv_fft(c);
```

At the end of this, the `r`'th element of the complex array `c` has a real part equal to the coefficient of `x**r` and an imaginary part of zero.
Now since this is all done in floating point you should be aware that those elements will have accumulated rounding errors. You can partially correct this by rounding them to the nearest integer but be aware that for sufficiently large `k` and `n` those errors will exceed 0.5 so this can yield results that are off by some small relative error.

A quick search on the web reveals than numpy has implementations of the FFT and its inverse, `numpy.fft.rfft` and `numpy.fft.irfft` respectively, that you can use when the input data is real.

Comment: Thanks for that reply. My knowledge in the field of Fourier transforms is lousy, so I am not sure how to transform your idea into code...

Comment: @Bach: I've corrected an error in which I stated that you should multiply the terms by `n` when you should, in fact, raise them to the power of `n`. I've also added some pseudo-code that will hopefully make it clearer.